# Django - how to filter using QuerySet to get subset of objects?

Tags: python, django

According to [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter):

> filter(**kwargs) Returns a new QuerySet containing objects that match
>   the given lookup parameters.
>
> The lookup parameters (**kwargs) should be in the format described in
>   Field lookups below. Multiple parameters are joined via AND in the
>   underlying SQL statement.

Which to me suggests it will return a subset of items that were in original set.
However I seem to be missing something as below example does not behave as I would expect:

```
>>> kids = Kid.objects.all()
>>> tuple(k.name for k in kids)
(u'Bob',)
>>> toys = Toy.objects.all()
>>> tuple( (t.name, t.owner.name) for t in toys)
((u'car', u'Bob'), (u'bear', u'Bob'))
>>> subsel = Kid.objects.filter( owns__in = toys )
>>> tuple( k.name for k in subsel )
(u'Bob', u'Bob')
>>> str(subsel.query)
'SELECT "bug_kid"."id", "bug_kid"."name" FROM "bug_kid" INNER JOIN "bug_toy" ON ("bug_kid"."id" = "bug_toy"."owner_id") WHERE "bug_toy"."id" IN (SELECT U0."id" FROM "bug_toy" U0)'
```

As you can see in above **subsel** ends up returning duplicate records, which is not what I wanted. My question is what is the *proper* way to get subset? (note: set by definition will not have multiple occurrences of the same object)

Explanation as to *why* it behaves like that would be also nice, as to me *filter* means what you achieve with **filter()** built-in function in Python. Which is: take elements that fulfill requirement (or in other words discard ones that do not). And this definition doesn't seem to allow introduction/duplication of objects.

I know can aplly **distinct()** to the whole thing, but that still results in rather ugly (and probably slower than could be) query:

```
>>> str( subsel.distinct().query )
'SELECT DISTINCT "bug_kid"."id", "bug_kid"."name" FROM "bug_kid" INNER JOIN "bug_toy" ON ("bug_kid"."id" = "bug_toy"."owner_id") WHERE "bug_toy"."id" IN (SELECT U0."id" FROM "bug_toy" U0)'
```

My **models.py** for completeness:

```
from django.db import models

class Kid(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Toy(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Kid, related_name='owns')
```

**edit**:

After a chat with @limelight the conclusion is that **my** problem is that I expect **filter()** to behave according to dictionary definition. And i.e. how it works in Python or any other sane framework/language.

More precisely if I have set `A = {x,y,z}` and I invoke `A.filter( <predicate> )` I don't expect any elements to get duplicated. With Django's QuerySet however it behaves like this:

```
A = {x,y,z}
A.filter( <predicate> )
# now A i.e. = {x,x}
```

So first of all the issue is inappropriate method name (something like **match()** would be much better).
Second thing is that I think it is possible to create more efficient query than what Django allows me to. I might be wrong on that, if I will have a bit of time I will probably try to check if that is true.

Comment: so you want distinct kids field?

Comment: Given subset of toys I want to get subset of kids that own those toys.
Actually I have slightly more complex case because in fact I have "owner" and "last_played_with" fields. And what I want is list of all kids that either own or played with those toys. And if possible I'd like to understand why **filter()** duplicates objects.

Comment: can you provide the model entirety? wit last_played and other related field.

Comment: Using `distinct()` isn't a bad practice nor will it slow down all that much. It's actually the recommended way short of writing your own SQL. As to `filter()` it's actually in the docs `By default, a QuerySet will not eliminate duplicate rows`.

Comment: @goromlagche: I can, not sure if it will help with explaining, only will make thing more complex

Comment: @limelights: problem I have with understanding that is that there are no duplicate rows in QuerySet that we are filtering, so there is nothing to eliminate

Comment: But there is, you're filtering with `__in`, so the `Toy` table has two rows (accordingly to your example) with `car` and `bear`.

Comment: From my understanding of how **filter()** should work it shouldn't introduce any joins (in this case at least), but only extend contents of WHERE clause.
As much as I do understand why that query returns what it returns, I do NOT understand why I get a query like this. Not to mention that Django is supposed to isolate me from actual SQL, so I'd like to understand semantics of that phrase. And no "__in" does not imply to me that it will produce duplicate items.

Comment: But you're saying "filter Kids based on what's __in Toys". It's really as simple as that. What's messing with you is that you're using `__in` since you're actually `__in`-ing over another QuerySet.

Comment: Yes, and "filter Kids based on what's __in Toys" by no means should duplicate kids. The set of kids that result from *filtering* should be *less or equal* to original set size.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36272/discussion-between-limelights-and-elmo)

Comment: @elmo and how to do distinct if the database backend doesn't support it? =D

Comment: @aRkadeFR I am not sure what you're asking exactly. [distinct()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) is there regardless of back-end (which means they work-around any possibly lacking DB back-end). And even if it wasn't IMHO query generated by `filter()` is borked, because it should not duplicate entries in first place, so there should be no need to use `distinct` in any form.

Comment: got an NotImplementedError: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend . But I can't reproduce it again. I must have done a wrong query.

Answer (score 10):

This is kind of ugly, but works (without any type safety):

```
toy_owners = Toy.objects.values("owner_id")  # optionally with .distinct()
Kid.objects.filter(id__in=toy_owners)
```

If performance is not an issue, I think @limelights is right.

PS!  I tested your query on Django 1.6b2 and got the same unnecessary complex query.

Answer (score 2):

Instead DISTINCT you can use GROUP BY (annotate in django) to get distinct kids.

```
toy_owners = Toy.objects.values_list("owner_id", flat=True).distinct()
Kid.objects.only('name').filter(pk__in=toy_owners).annotate(count=Count('owns'))
```

Comment: This doesn't work, you're using two queries and you're not using GROUP BY.  Try your code with:

    Kid(id=100, name="Peter").save()
    Kid(id=101, name="John").save()
    Toy(name="car", owner_id=100).save()
    Toy(name="bear", owner_id=100).save()

Comment: And after your edit, you have two queries, the last one is `SELECT "app_kid"."id", "app_kid"."name", COUNT("app_toy"."id") AS "count" FROM "app_kid" LEFT OUTER JOIN "app_toy" ON ( "app_kid"."id" = "app_toy"."owner_id" ) WHERE "app_kid"."id" IN (100) GROUP BY "app_kid"."id", "app_kid"."name"`.